# Error: Resolved Credential Object is not valid -> S3 Bucket Upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

Basically what the title says. I am trying to set up a middleware for profile picture handling on a mobile app using express and node for the backend. What I want to happen is to send the data from a form from frontend to backend and then the middleware takes the image that the user selected for their profile picture, uploads it to an S3 bucket and then stores the url of the image in the database document.

I have a middleware file in my backend directory which contains the following:

```
import multer from "multer";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Readable } from "stream";

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  },
});

const bufferToStream = (buffer) => {
  const stream = new Readable({
    read() {
      this.push(buffer);
      this.push(null);
    },
  });
  return stream;
};

const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

export const uploadFileToS3 = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Middleware body: ", req.body);
  console.log("credentials: ", process.env.AWS_KEY, process.env.AWS_SECRET);
  console.log("Middleware file: ", req.file);
  // console.log("S3 config?: ", s3);

  if (!req.file) {
    return next();
  }

  const fileStream = bufferToStream(req.file.buffer);

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `${Date.now()}-${req.file.originalname}`,
    Body: fileStream,
    ContentType: req.file.mimetype,
  };

  try {
    await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));

    req.fileUrl = `https://${uploadParams.Bucket}.s3.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${uploadParams.Key}`;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading file to S3: ", error);
    next(error);
  }
};

export default upload;
```

Now when trying to execute the PutObjectCommand to actually upload the image to the S3 bucket, I am receiving an error that the "Resolved Credential Object is not valid. Here is the full error trace:

```
An error was encountered in a non-retryable streaming request.
Error uploading file to S3:  Error: Resolved credential object is not valid
    at _SignatureV4S3Express.validateResolvedCredentials (/Users/user/Desktop/SipSync/backend/node_modules/@smithy/signature-v4/dist-cjs/index.js:440:13)
    at _SignatureV4S3Express.signRequest (/Users/user/Desktop/SipSync/backend/node_modules/@smithy/signature-v4/dist-cjs/index.js:365:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error: Resolved credential object is not valid
    at _SignatureV4S3Express.validateResolvedCredentials (/Users/user/Desktop/SipSync/backend/node_modules/@smithy/signature-v4/dist-cjs/index.js:440:13)
    at _SignatureV4S3Express.signRequest (/Users/user/Desktop/SipSync/backend/node_modules/@smithy/signature-v4/dist-cjs/index.js:365:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Everything seems to be logging fine from the environment variables so it's not that causing the issue. I have a web app that uses the same credentials and a similar process to handle image uploads and it is still working perfectly fine so it is not the credentials themselves either. I have also tried creating a second set of credentials to no success.

Does anybody have any inkling of an idea as to why I am getting this error message currently?

Comment: i think your mobile app is likely not handling `dotenv` variables the same way as your web app does. can you log the s3 credentials on the mobile app to verify the credentials?